# how to share my message in facebook?

Tags: asp.net

i am having message content in my girdview how to share this ?
i have one button share to facebook  when click inthis button share this content in my facebook account ?

Comment: Basiclly you have two way to go, server-side via the the c# sdk or client-side via the javascript sdk. If you pick one, I can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.net a really useful SDK to use is the Facebook SDK.

You can download it at - http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/

It has full support for the Facebook Graph API. It will allow you to share info on Facebook.